# GNU Prolog: Strange characters

Tags: prolog

I  am new to using GNU Prolog.

Given the following facts:

```
theme(cafe).
role(manager).
role(boss).
role(coworker).
numberOfCharacters(theme(cafe), 3).
charactersRole(numberCharacters(theme(cafe), 3), role('boss'), role('manager'), role('çoworker')).
```

When I query:

```
charactersRole(numberCharacters(theme('cafe'), 3), role(X), role(Y), role(Z)).
```

It returns some of the values correctly, while one value contains Ã§ in place of normal character 'c'.

```
X = boss
Y = manager
Z = 'Ã§oworker'
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: No need to put quotes around `'cafe'` and the other names.

Answer (score 2):

```
role('çoworker')
```

You have cedilla right here, which gets misrepresented by two characters, usually by not being unicode-aware. This is not a Prolog issue.

Ã§ are `U+00C3 U+00A7` in Unicode

And ç is

```
U+00E7 LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
UTF-8: 0xC3 0xA7
```

That's what you're getting by outputting an UTF-8 2-byte character into non-UTF8-aware LATIN1 terminal.

Comment: Is there any other way to actually display the 'c'?

Comment: @MichaelJoshuaRamos use non-unicode input if you want real 'ç' - `iconv -f utf-8 -t latin1 file.utf > file.lat` basically

Comment: @MichaelJoshuaRamos or replace c with cedilla with a regular c, because I think this is what you need. You probably just hit the wrong buttons on your keyboard, just retype the "coworker" in the last line.

Comment: Thank you so much. The fact was role('coworker'). Another fact was role('çoworker'), I accidently type çoworker. :). It worked, thanks.